# how to check if incoming request to express backend is coming from a firebase authenticated client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

I am authenticating my react frontend client with firebase and am also using a custom node express backend.

How can I check, by using firebase-admin SDK on the backend that an incoming request to my backend is coming from a client which is authenticated by firebase auth?

Comment: You can't, unless you are writing code to add authentication information in the request and also writing code to verify that information.  Please read the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens